# What is the english for 4 times or 4x?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, numbers

Sometimes we use the verb *"double"*,e.g., *"he **doubled** my pocket money"*, and sometimes we use *"triple"* as verb- but what is the verb when the issue is about getting 4 times or 4x of a thing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word you are looking for is [*Quadruple.*](https://www.google.com/#q=profits+quadrupled)

> Commerzbank, Germany's second biggest bank, said Friday that its profits *quadrupled* in 2015 and it would resume...

The series continues from there, *double, triple, quadruple, quintuple, sextuple, septuple, octuple...* but after quadruple, the terms are [less and less common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=quadruple%2Cquintuple%2Csextuple%2Cseptuple%2Coctuple&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cquadruple%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bquadruple%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BQuadruple%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BQUADRUPLE%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cquintuple%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bquintuple%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BQuintuple%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BQUINTUPLE%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Csextuple%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsextuple%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSextuple%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSEXTUPLE%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cseptuple%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bseptuple%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSeptuple%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Coctuple%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Boctuple%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BOctuple%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BOCTUPLE%3B%2Cc0). I don't think I have ever used anything past *quintuple*.

Similar is *four-fold:*

> *My hair grew from 2 inches to 8 inches in one month.  A four-fold increase!*

Answer (score 1):

`Quadruple` and `Fourfold` both work. They are both adjectives, although Quadruple is more common.
Go to [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple) for a full list of tuples. (words for 5x, 6x, etc)

Comment: I don't think "fourfold" works as a verb, does it?